# VB.NET Chaining commands to cmd.exe

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I've been trying to chain commands to firstly self delete an application then delete the directory in which it resided through a process in a vb.net application. Here's where I am at as far as code is concerned.

I found a useful code sample for self deleting applications:

```
Dim fldpath as String = "C:\test"
Dim inf as ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
inf.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " & """" Application.ExecutablePath & """"
inf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
inf.CreateNoWindow = True
inf.Verb = "runas"
inf.UseShellExecute = True
inf.FileName = "cmd.exe"
Process.Start(inf)
Application.Exit()
```

The above code works a treat and self deletes the application. I'd, however, also like to delete the folder in which it resides. I have tried chaining the commands in the arguments to the process but only the application deletion happens and the folder remains, e.g:

```
inf.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " & """" Application.ExecutablePath & """" & "&rmdir /s /q " & """" & fldpath & """"
```

Concatenating the rmdir command does not yield results, even simply recursively deleting the directory (and not bothering with the application deletion) does not seem to work.

EDIT:
Further to comments given thus far, I have also preiously tried simply recursively removing the directory without success, aka with the argument as:

```
inf.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & rmdir /s /q " & """" & fldpath & """"
```

The above deletes the file but does not remove the folder. If I show the cmd prompt, the error is to the effect that the file is still in se by another application.

```
inf.Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del /s /q " & """" & Application.ExecutablePath & """"
```

The above deletes the file without issue. I need to chain another command to remove the containing directory.

Just a further clarification. It seems the error "Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" relates to directories! I added an empty directory and another text file then run the command. All the files were deleted BUT failed on the new folder with the /s switch off.

```
inf.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
```

Changing the working directory as above (from the default, I assume, current one) did not yield results. As noted above, the process fails on directories and not the chaining, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can just remove the file name from the `Application.ExecutablePath` and try the `rmdir` again.

Comment: No it does not work and I have tried it. I simply expressly declared the folder path in the question to be clear on that though could have equally done string manipulation on the executable path to get it.

Comment: The point is, you don't need the `Del` command. This will work just fine: `"rmdir /s /q " & """" & Application.StartupPath & """"`

Comment: @VisualVincent - see edit. I have tried that and it does not remove the directory! I also tried RD.

Comment: RD and RMDIR are the same command. Still though, if it doesn't work then it's probably something locking one of the files in the directory. Perhaps you should show the cmd window instead so you can see if it gives you any errors instead of simply saying _"it does not work"_? - Because I just tested your code and it works fine to me.

Comment: @VisualVincent - first, your suggested answer can not work because the calling file will still be in use. If I add the preceeding arguments, i.e /C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 then all the files will be deleted but NOT the folder (which was the main question here).

Comment: My suggestion was that you should remove the `Del` command, not the one adding a three-second delay. When I test the exact same code as in your edit, everything (including the folder itself) is removed.

Comment: Either way, simply replacing Del still results in the file being used by another process remark (even extending the delay does the same). Like I suggested, I think the solution lies in chaining the commands by ensuring that the calling application is deleted first, but can not get it to work.  Question still stands.

Comment: In that case the application wouldn't get deleted by `Del` either, so it shouldn't make a difference. What happens if you manually delete the folder right after the app has closed?

Comment: No, the application gets deleted with Del. Manually trying to delete the folder results in the folder being deleted, as expected. Rather than speculate, it may be helpful if you tried it yourself and it will become apparent to you. I tried MANY permutations of both the Del and rmdir commands before I resorted to asking here (just so you know).

Comment: I already said that I've tried it. And I also said that it works completely as expected! I'm not speculating anything, what I say is based on true fact; if the file is opened/in use by a process RMDIR nor DEL won't be able to delete it. -- [Quoting my previous comment again:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831733/vb-net-chaining-commands-to-cmd-exe#comment65030381_38831733) _"When I test the **exact same code** as in your edit, everything (including the folder itself) is removed."_

Comment: I have tested and I am unable to, in any way, reproduce your problem.

Comment: OK, I think you did not get the real question in the first place. Del removes the calling application and any files, rmdir also does (including any child directories if supplied with the /s flag) BUT not the parent directory. The question was how to remove the PARENT directory too (in which the now deleted calling application resided). All your answers thus far have simply skirted that (the) question. Honestly, I am not stupid.

Comment: I understood your question completely the very first time I read it. Do you understand that I cannot reproduce your problem? When I try your code the parent directory is removed without a problem. -- And for the record I have not been skirting anything. My responses so far has been **1)** Saying that the use of `DEL` is unnecessary if you remove everything using RMDIR. **2)** Asked you to show the window to see if it throws any errors _(this definitely concerns your question)_ **3)** Explaining that your application would not get removed by either DEL or RMDIR if it was in use.

Comment: Moving on from our unnecessary discussion about what we understand and don't understand (it isn't getting us anywhere)... You say that you get the _"Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"_ error even though all files seem to be successfully deleted, so either something's locking the directory itself or a hidden file in it. You could try using some tool like _Procexp_ (or Procmon?), which perhaps can help you tell which process uses which file... -- May I also ask what does your application do (shortly summarized)?

Comment: Let me also ask this: What happens if you create a completely new project where you implement this code? Does it still not delete the directory?